# Simulation of Lévy walk

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walks, levy-processes

I have problems to find out how to do discrete simulation of the Lévy walk. I can sum my doubts in a few questions:

1. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight) it seems to me that Lévy flight can be produced just by integration of samples with Lévy distribution, in other words: $x(k+1) = x(k) + v(k)$, were $v(k)$ is a random sample from Lévy distribution. Is this correct?
2. How can I generate a Lévy distribution? Can I convert random samples from other distribution to random samples with Lévy distribution? If yes, please add a reference.
3. What is the difference between Lévy walk and Lévy flight?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks a lot! The blog post seems to be really useful. Unfortunately the chapter is not accessible from my university, but I will try to find different paper on the topic once more. What about the first question? Is my idea in 1. correct or not? This is probably my most crucial problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Indeed, the Lévy flight is a random walk where the step increments $\nu$ are i.i.d. with a Lévy distribution, $p(\nu)\rightarrow 1/\nu^{1+\alpha}$ for $\nu\rightarrow\infty$, with exponent $0<\alpha<2$.
2. [Generating Lévy random variables from Gaussian.](http://andreweckford.blogspot.nl/2011/05/generating-levy-random-variables-from.html)
3. The difference between a Lévy flight and a Lévy walk is whether each step takes the same time irrespective of its length (Lévy flight), or whether the time is proportional to the step length (Lévy walk). A Lévy flight implies an unbounded velocity, which is unphysical. Further reading: [Lévy walks versus Lévy flights.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-5165-5_29#page-1)

Comment: Last question - when I generate the Lévy noise, then the lévy flight is if I use equal sampling for every noise step (no matter of value). And the Lévy walk will be If I will split greater noise samples between more steps? (in other words, the time samples will have different size, corresponding to the value of noise sample?). Is it so?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this last question.